# I can't open Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mavericks, java-8

I just recently upgraded my MacBook Pro from OSX 10.6.8 (Leopard) to OSX Maverick.
I want to use Eclipse as an IDE for Java. But everytime I try to open Eclipse it says:

```
  "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
      Version 1.7 or greater is required."
```

So I went to the Oracle website at 
           http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
and downloaded JDK8.I tried to open Eclipse and it is telling me the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I downloaded both Eclipse for both OSX 32 bit and 64 bit and I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: When you do `java -version` from the terminal, what does it say?  It may still be finding the older jdk in your environment.

Comment: I cant open Eclipse at all. I dont think I downloaded Java 8 correctly. I just downlaoded and left in a folder. I thought Mac OSX Maverick came with 1.7 JVM.

Comment: Where do I go to download the 1.7 JVM or the latest one? I have a Java programming class next week and I want to be ready to use it.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work.  My Mavericks came with a version of 1.6 if I recall.  Download the Oracle installer, and run that.  Also, I meant you should open a terminal, run `java -version`, and see what the output is.

Comment: Never mind. I downloaded the wrong file. I have Eclipse up and running again. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Download AND install the OSX (.dmg) file from this page:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction to make sure correct environment variables:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

**Later, with Eclipse IDE:**

- Choose **Prefences** (Preferences is under the Eclipse menu on Mac OS X )
- Select **Java**-> **Installed JREs**
- Select **Add**
- Select **Standard VM**
- Set the directory to your 1.8 JDK directory.